# Can't run pyinstaller on macos from zsh after installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I installed pyinstaller successfully by using `pip3 install pyinstaller`

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (49.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (0.17)
Requirement already satisfied: macholib>=1.8; sys_platform == "darwin" in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (1.14)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyinstaller) (2020.11)
```

and btw, my `echo $PATH` returns:

```
/Users/apple/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

However, when I try to run this following code in my terminal in the same directory, it doesn't work:

```
apple@apples-MBP-2 app4.1_using_OOP % pyinstaller --onefile --windowed frontend.py
```

and it has the error:

```
zsh: command not found: pyinstaller
```

I tried many ways including:

1. Downgrading pip to 18.1 and run `pip3 install pyinstaller` again
2. Used `apple@apples-MBP-2 app4.1_using_OOP % python -m PyInstaller frontend.py` and it does run and has a disc folder where there is a file named `frontend.app`, but I can't open it.

Questions:

1. Why sometimes I can directly use the modules downloaded by `pip3` but sometimes I can't?
2. If I want to add to my `$PATH`, do I add `/Library/Frameworks`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This command worked for me:

`python3 -m PyInstaller your_script.py`